# Saving Photos to Core Data

Tags: ios, core-data, save, photo

I want to save photo to Core Data.  I look up in the internet and find many resources about core data however I cannot find the one that I want to accomplish.  I want to use Core Data to save images that the user has taken and then want the user to select which category he wants to save it.  Its like he is sorting the pictures into Categories for example meat or vegetables or etc.  To do this I have made one entity called photo and put 6 attributes name of the Categories for example meat vegetables. I did not select the type yet.  I am thinking that the user chooses the category and save it an attribute.  Here's the question.  I want to do this but I cannot find resources that meet what I want to do.  Also am I doing the correct thinking of using multiple attributes?

Answer (score 1):

Scroll down for storing UIImage data in core data, but firstly a bit about core data attributes: you shouldn't use multiple attributes for different categories, you should have a single attribute called 'category'. This could be an integer or string, depending on your implementation. I recommend using an integer and defining an enum for it as follows:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyFoodCategory){
    MyFoodCategoryVegetable = 0,
    MyFoodCategoryMeat = 1,
    MyFoodCategoryFish = 2,
    MyFoodCategorySweet = 3,
};
```

When you print this out to the view, do something like the following:

```
-(void)setLabelTextForCategory:(MyFoodCategory)category
{
    switch(category) {
        case MyFoodCategoryVegetable:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Vegetable";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryMeat:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Meat";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryFish:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Poisson"; //French
            break;
        case MyFoodCategorySweet:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Dessert";
            break;
    }
}
```

This means that if you change your mind about what test you wish to print for each category, then you only have to change it in this place, and you don't have to change what is in core database. For example, you could use localization to display a different language or variant of the same word.

**Storing UIImage data in core data**

OK, so to answer your main question. I would personally avoid storing image data in core data, I would save it to disk instead. Look into using NSFileManager class or convert UIImage to NSData and write to file, e.g.

```
UIImage *image = ...
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image); // or use UIImageJPEGRepresentation if it's a jpeg image

NSString *documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
NSString *fileName = @"imageWhatever1";
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
NSError *writeError = nil;
if (![data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to write file: %@", writeError);
}
```

However, if you would prefer to save the image directly to core data, then create an attribute called 'imageData' and set the Attribute Type to 'Binary Data'. Then save the NSData object to the core data entity. When you read the NSData object, you can convert it back to UIImage as follows:

```
UIImage *imageLoadedFromDiskOrCoreData = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

Comment: It's also nice to use a custom `NSValueTransformer` for nonstandard attributes like images. Apple even provides a sample implementation of this in their **PhotoLocations** sample app.

Comment: I want to make the user select which category to save to using a `UIPickerView` but I can not make it work.  What will be a good starting point for me to do it?

Answer (score 0):

No. This isn't a good way. For now, you are having a `six attributes` for each `entity`. This will lead to **create useless 5 attributes** for each row in your database.

Instead of that, you can create an `enum` for your `Category` and store the `enum` value in your `coreData`.

**So that you can add any number of categories in your `enum` for future enhancement too** and you don't need to care about what you are storing in `coreData`.

Just like this.

```
typedef enum imageType {
     vegetables = 0,
     fruits = 1,
     animals = 2,
     scenaries = 3,
     Nature = 4,
     Home = 5,
     Architecture = 6
}
```

and your `coreData` entity be like this.

**ImageEntity**

```
 NSData *imageData;
 NSNumber *typeEnum;
```

You can have an array with the names of your category and use it all over your app to match the `enum` with the exact name of a category in your `UIPickerView` or in some other components.

Your array could be like this.

```
NSArray *categoryArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"vegetables", @"fruits", @"animals", @"scenaries", @"Nature", @"Home", @"Architecture", nil];
```

And you can access the array objects like this.

```
NSString *imageCategory = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:imageType.animals];
```